# Bash while() loop :: Does this process cmd line arguments?

Tags: bash, while-loop, syntax, command-line-arguments

I'm a Bash newbie, and I'm puzzling through a Bash script where I see this:

```
while [ $# -ge 2 ]
  if [ "x$1" = "x-a" ]; then
    echo "STR_A = $2" >>tmpFile.txt
    ...do more stuff...
  elif [ "x$1" = "x-b" ]; then
    echo "STR_B = $2" >>tmpFile.txt
    ...do more stuff...
  else
    usage
done
```

The script takes in four (or five?) command line arguments, and that `usage` function is:

```
usage() {
   echo "usage: myscript -a STR_A | -b STR_B" 1>&2
   exit 1
}
```

So suppose I ran the script like this:

```
me@ubuntu1:~$./myscript -A apple -B banana
```

I'm guessing that this code processes the script's command line arguments.  I think that the outer `while()` loop steps through the command line arguments after argument 1, which would be `myscript`.  The inner `if()` statements check to see an `-a` or `-b` flag is used to supply arguments, and then records the text string that follows in `tmpFile.txt`.  Anything outside of those parameters is rejected and the script exits.

A lot of these assumptions rest on the bet that the outer `while()` loop...

```
while [ $# -ge 2 ]
```

...means "*parse the BASH argv[] after the first argument*", (to put this in C terms.)  If that's not a correct assumption, then I have no idea what's going on here.  Any feedback is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why not use the bash builtin `getopts`? I'm sure you will find copious examples on the web.

Comment: Is there in `do more stuff` a `shift` within the loop? if so: yes it probably goes through the command line arguments. But the code is rather ugly.

Comment: The `[ "x$1" = "x-a" ]` conditions are outdated. It's sufficient to write `[ "$1" = "-a" ]` or if you're using bash specifically `[[ "$1" == "-a" ]]`. The "x" version was only necessary on very old Bourne shells where empty variables in `[...]` were not properly handled.

Comment: @Bib Thanks for writing, Bib.  The script wasn't written by me, I'm stuck with it as is.  Alas...

Comment: The usage seems to indicate that you can specify *either* `-a` or `-b` (not both), and not that `|` is an argument to separate the two. (Though the code shown doesn't seem to enforce that only one can be provided.)

Comment: @LjmDullaart Thanks for writing.  No, no `shift` in that part of the code.  Truthfully, it looks like the code just records the text string in a temp file; I omitted that stuff as lard in my post

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks Glen, that's so interesting!  I have no idea how old this script it, you are making me think it is much older than I guessed.  (Or the original author is an older fellow)

Comment: @chepner Thanks Chepner, yeah I guess the original author meant that there was to be either A or B, not both.  Perhaps that's why he used the while() loop?  I wish I knew....

Comment: If it doesn't use `shift` or `break` or `exit` or something like that, the loop will run forever, because if `[ $# -ge 2 ]` is true once it'll remain true unless something changes it (e.g. `shift` removes arguments, and hence decreases `$#`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson My apologies, there is a "shift" outside the inner if/elif/else statements.  I guess that must be what you expected.

Comment: The author seems to assume that the `shift` statement will always reduce `$#` to something greater than or equal to 2, or to 0, never leaving  a single argument left. (That may be a bad assumption on the part of the author.)

Comment: @chepner Hmmmm...  Could be.  I began looking at this script assuming it was debugged.  Maybe that's my error right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code explanation.

```
while [ $# -ge 2 ]
```

There is a missing `do` for the loop.

This should loop forever if there are two or more arguments, unless `shift` is used. If there are less than two arguments, the loop does not even start.

```
  if [ "x$1" = "x-a" ]; then
```

In distant past, it was common to prevent empty strings by adding an extra letter. Nowadays you would `if [ "$1" = "-a" ]; then`.

```
  else
    usage
```

Note that the `usage` is called from within the loop. So, if I would call the script as `myscript -a`, I would not get a usage message. On the other hand, if I would `myscript bla bla`, I would get an endless stream of error messages, which is probably not what you want.

I would seriously edit the script; determine whether the `while` is indeed a loop-forever or whether it is used instead of an `if`, and try the `getops` for argument parsing.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help understand the code you're reading, but I do option parsing like this:

```bash
# inititialize vars, not strictly required in this case
a=''
b=''

# process options
while getopts "ha:b:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) a=$OPTARG ;;
        b) b=$OPTARG ;;
        *) usage     ;;
    esac
done

# shift after the processing
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# look for error conditions
if [[ -n $a && -n $b ]]; then
    echo "only one of -a or -b should be given" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

[`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) is a bash builtin